# change image sprite on click for button using CSS

Tags: css, button, onclick, sprite

change button image onclick then return to original image after click

```
<style>
img.button-send {
background: url(img/agentsprite.png) 0 0;
width:87px;
height:34px;
opacity:0;
}
img.button-send:active {
background: url(img/agentsprite.png) 34 174;
width:87px;
height:34px;
}

</style>
      <button type="submit">
      <img class="button-send" src="img/img_trans.gif" width="1" height="1" />
          </button>
```

i'm using a sprite for this, and it seems that it won't go to that image position when i click it, is there any way for this to work ? i wan't to have a button effect for this field when pressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

...........................

hi now used to **px value** in your `background-position` image

as like this

```
img.button-send:active {
background: url(img/agentsprite.png) 34px 174px;
}
```

or you can used this also

```
img.button-send:active {
    background-position:34px 174px;
    }
```

`px` value according to your **design**

Comment: oh so that's what i'm missing'

Comment: it works now gotta have to wait for 10mins before i can accept your ans